# How to visually indicate whether a window is `Always On Top`?

Tags: window

Set window **Always On Top** is very useful.
How to visually indicate whether a window is **Always On Top**?

For example, add a icon like:

[image: Smeigtukas]

at the top right corner. Or change the color of the border...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm partially there. If you go into CompizConfig and enable commands, you can set one of the commands to something that will modify the window appearance. Then you can set the key binding for it to the same binding you use to toggle Always On Top. I just don't know how to make it change the appearance of the window. I was trying `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE -b toggle,shaded` which I thought would toggle a shadow, but it hides/unhides the window. Not really what I was going for. Keep in mind you have to install the wmctrl package for that to work.

I don't know of any readily supported ways to modify the appearance a single window. I looked into using `gtk-window-decorator`, but it only appears to let you reload the settings for all of the windows. Maybe somebody else can chime in and complete this answer, but I personally can't figure a way out!